# Is Trump tweeting himself on realDonaldTrump?

Tags: donald-trump, twitter

I have heard that most of the politicians today have some employees who manage all the social media accounts like Facebook, Twitter, etc. and they don't post/tweet anything themselves.

I think that is reasonable but there are several sources that claim to have found evidence that many tweets are actually from Trump himself like on this article:
[Text analysis of Trump's tweets confirms he writes only the (angrier) Android half](http://varianceexplained.org/r/trump-tweets/)

The analysis is quite interesting, but are there further proofs that support the result? Or are there proofs against the analysis? Maybe there is a strategical reason for doing this so my question is:

Is there a proof that at least some of the tweets are actually from Donald Trump and not from his employees? Actually i don't know how to define a proof in this case, maybe a trustworthy interview or a reliable source. What could be a reliable proof?

Comment: I don't think we can answer this question on these terms. We should allow all evidence, present it, and then decide how convincing it is. Sometimes we only have partial evidence, and that's okay. As it is currently posed, the question sets an arbitrarily high level of proof, which makes it opinion based.

Comment: @Sklivvz How can I change the question to fit this requirement? Soften the last paragraph?

Comment: Surely this could be proven with a single photo of post-election Trump typing into the Twitter app on his phone? Since the US president is typically one of the most photographed people on earth, that doesn't seen like an unreasonably high standard.

Comment: Can you analyze writing 160 characters at a time?

Comment: @izlin I think that the problem is mostly here *"I don't think it is a full proof because it is still possible that his social media guys do it by purpose"*. This same reasoning can disprove 99% of the evidence we can give, and it's contrary to how skeptics think: you can't dismiss evidence without other evidence.

Comment: @Sklivvz I changed the sentence you mentioned a bit. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: What on earth is the point of this question ? It's pretty clear that @readlDonaldTrump represents what The Donald actually thinks. Whether or not he types the words is of no reasonable significance.

Comment: You might be interested in [this blog post](http://varianceexplained.org/r/trump-tweets/). Data suggests that, at the very least, @realDonaldTrump tweets are not all written by the same person.

Comment: @ff524 That's exactly the same link I already posted in my question ;)

Comment: During the Second Presidential Debate, Hillary Clinton accused Trump of saying that climate change was a Chinese hoax, as is stated on Trump's Twitter page.  In response, Trump repeatedly, explicitly denied having ever said that.  If Trump was telling the truth (admittedly a big "if"), then that'd imply that someone else has been posting on his Twitter account.  And since it was such a popular and controversial tweet but has yet to be deleted, it'd also suggest that he is aware of and accepts others posting on his Twitter (rather than it being a hacker's vandalism).

Comment: I note the above example because it's so readily verifiable.  The Second Presidential Debate was broadcast on live television and streamed/stored on sites like YouTube, showing Trump clearly stating his claim in his own words, and the relevant tweet's still on his Twitter that he officially endorses as his.  We rarely get such solid, well-verified evidence for stuff like this.